# Commenting out all the calls of specific function?

Tags: vim, coding-style

How can I comment out all the calls of same function with a simple vim command?

For example I want to comment out all the debug calls of python `pdb.set_trace()`

Answer (score 5):

Did you try the following?

```
:g/pdb.set_trace()/norm I#
```

The `:global` command executes the command that comes after the search pattern on every matching line.

```
:g/foo/d <-- deletes every line containing foo
```

The `:normal` command allows you to execute a normal mode command from the command line or a script.

```
:norm I# <-- inserts a # before the first printable character of the current line
```

See `:help :global` and `:help :normal`.

Comment: thanks...that's awesome...i suppose putting that line into a vim function is easy too...